# What is the total collective time saved by the invention of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, time

What do you think is the total time saved on debugging, Google-searching, testing, etc..., by all of the developers of the world collectively as a result of Stack Overflow providing quick, reliable answers to their issues?

Comment: If we factor Meta in, it would be 0. Also, stackoverflow wasn't *invented* IMHO, just as a Ford Mustang isn't *invented*.

Comment: Perform an empirical study. Have you and your team exclude _all_ research on SO for a month. After that time period, research all issues on SO (for questions/answers that would already have existed during that time frame) and see what the time difference is. (I know, small sample, but it's a start.)

Comment: Related questions: [How has SOFU ruined/changed your life?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/how-has-sofu-ruined-changed-your-life) and [Do you think SO has changed the internet?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48590/do-you-think-so-has-changed-the-internet)

Comment: SO brokes the internet, but don't worry the System Lord of the Internets will fix it.

Comment: LOL @Lance. I haven't seen his rants the past few days. Maybe he's just saving up for a new round of craptastic fun?

Comment: @Josh, you just missed a great one today, but it got deleted quick (after it got to -19).

Comment: @Lance: Damn, those are always so much fun! :-)

Comment: @Josh, when you get to 10k, you can check it out, just look for the one about cars.

Comment: LOL @Lance again! It's taken me 10 months to get above 1K... I should have enough rep in 2020... :-)

Comment: Don't feed the troll by glorifying his rants. @lan

Comment: @The Cat: I know, you're probably right. But if we can't derive pleasure out of his incessant trolling than I feel like he wins

Comment: @Josh: When he derails others (negatively *or* otherwise, such as 'love-to-hate him'), he wins.  SO is uniquely positioned among similar tools to vote down, close, delete, and otherwise community moderate trolls so they have little impact (and hopefully eventually give up, talking to an audience of 3 isn't as entertaining as an audience of 300).  Or to use a cliché: hate isn't the opposite of love, apathy is.

Comment: @The Cat: Ok. I see what you mean, well said. It doesn't cause me to like to laugh at him any less, but you do make a good point. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a Absolute perspective: **Negatively Infinite**.

The time caused by the addiction, outweighs the time saved on question searches.

From a Relative perspective: **Infinite**.

I've had problems solved here, that I would never have solved without the help, after days of looking all over the internet.

Comment: Which just about amounts to "immeasurable". :P

Comment: @mat, Yes, you were right on.

Comment: +1 for Negatively Infinite!

Comment: $\infty-\infty=\text{undefined}$

Comment: If you did learn something or people had problem solved caused by your addiction then it's not time lost.

Answer (score 7):

Immeasurable.

Comment: +1. Who knows whether it's even positive or negative? :)

Answer (score 3):

For the time saved searching, and the knowledge gained: priceless.

For everything else, there's *a card with two circles with SO and SF colors kissing on it*.

Comment: -1 for copyright infringement

Comment: +1 for copyright infringement

Comment: Nicely done, Gnoupi. Hopefully nobody from MC saw what the response looked like before!

Comment: I'm pretty sure "For everything else, there's a card with two circles with SO and SF colors kissing on it" infringes upon some copyright. Wasn't there some commercials with that slogan for Master Unicorn?

Answer (score 1):

It's approximately

```
1 / ± 0
```

Jon Skeet can give you the [precise answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Answer (score 0):

About 1% of the time lost because of the invention of the internet :)

Answer (score 0):

The company has offered a number for the amount of times a developer got help, [in the about page](https://stackoverflow.co/) it currently says:

> #### 50.6+ billion
>
> Times a developer got help

So if you consider each of those times 1 minute it would give roughly 96.270 years.

The number itself has been discussed on Meta Stack Overflow, see ["46.8+ Billion Times a developer got help" - how is this calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401930/10794031)